# Connecting to a colleagues computer over VPN when both of us are working remotely

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, remote-access, remote

I'm looking for some guidance on connecting to a colleagues computer to offer technical assistance when we are both out of the office and working remotely.

We have a Unity Security Gateway with a VPN Subnet setup.

They are connecting to the office network using the Windows 10 VPN and I am connecting using the Mac VPN connection.

They have enabled Remote Desktop on their windows machine.

I have set the VPN connection to allow traffic through port 3389 using the forward IP as that of the subnet for the VPN.

When connecting to the VPN, does this essentially circumnavigate the allowed ports by their home router or is it the case that their home router will need 3389 open also?

I'd like to use Microsoft Remote Desktop, or No Machine to perform this.

Comment: You won't be able to share the screen using RDP. Use Remote Assistance, Quick Assist, or some third party screensharing tool. - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026516/windows-use-remote-assistance-to-let-someone-fix-your-pc

Comment: You could even make this simpler by doing the remote screen share not through the VPN and have only one person RDP into the end system.

Answer (score 0):

The home router would not need those same ports open as a tunnel is created.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/441497)

Comment: It answers the only question asked in the post.